# Is it OK to use a trimmer when my reel mower does not work?

Tags: grass, lawn-mower

I recently bought a house and have this 250 sqft backyard with really tall grass (about 7 inches). I found an 18" push reel mower and an electric trimmer (weedeater) thing in the garage. The reel mower is not able to cut anything, I guess, since the grass is really tall plus the blades looks really dull to me. So my question is: can I use the electrical trimmer to cut 1/3rd of the grass in the entire lawn a couple of times and then go back to using the reel mower when the grass gets manageable. I mean, is it OK to use the trimmer for the lawn, or are they specifically meant for edges and would destroy the lawn if used to cover the entire area?

Comment: Sure, go for it. I've used a machete to trim my grass. It's all about what kind of result you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well a trimmer won't destroy the lawn but it won't do a good job.  It is difficult to keep the trimmer head at exactly the same height.

Try this:

- Use a sharpener on the blades, even sandpaper will help.
- oil all the moving parts of the mower, WD40, lubricating oil or whatever comes to hand
- **Do wear protective gear when using a trimmer**. Gloves and glasses are essential if you don't know what's overgrown under the grass
- using the trimmer reduce the lawn height to three to four inches
- use the reel mower to give a nice clean cut.

Edit: Ok, maybe not WD40...

Comment: Repeat after me: "WD40 is **not** a lubricant! I shall **not** use it to oil/lubricate _anything_!" :)

Comment: Thanks kevinsky. That's what I plan to do albeit I'm getting my mower sharpened by a professional shop (I checked blades on new ones and mine look as if they won't even cut butter).